# git double pull request in different branches (branched from their parents)

Tags: git, github

I have a missunderstanding / problem :

- we have two branches : **develop** , **release**

For some taks lets say task **A_*** we should branch from **develop** and PR in **develop**.

For tasks **B_*** we should branch from **develop PR in develop** , branch from **release and PR in release**

I know something is about cherry-pick commit or something so we dont need to stash our unstaged files and apply stash both right ?

Can this be done more effective ? And in the other case that i need to do it exactly like this can someone tell me some steps.

I use github and Git IDE like Sourcetree/GitKracken

Thanks

Comment: You want git help but not git commands? I would recommend that you read up on _branching strategies_, especially _gitflow_.

Comment: ok or git commands but i need to understand the flow :( i am not expert in git and ... i was only refering to cases for the B tasks

Comment: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ - Gitflow

Comment: @evolutionxbox i dont have the clearance to alter this git flow .. it was already decided :(